# How many String objects will be created in the java string pool?

Tags: java, string, concatenation, pool

```
String hello = "Hello";
String world = " World!";
String bye = "Bye";
String greeting = hello + world;
String goodbye = bye + world;
```

I know with the first three that there's a new object created in the java String pool, but with the last two i'm not sure.

Are there just references to both string pool objects in the greeting and goodbye variables, or are there 2 new String objects created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you example just the first 3 will be created in the string pool and the last two will be a string object in the heap.
The reason that when you concatenate string using the + operator it will check if the resulting string is existed in the string pool then it will return a reference otherwise it will create a new String object even though the strings that you are using to create the new one are already in the pool.
You can test that when you do the following:

```
greeting == "Hello World!" 
goodbye == "Bye World!"
```

it will return false in both cases which shows that these are not in the pool.

Comment: I was checking if it's in the pool or not with the == operator, and as far as i can tell it's not even chekcing the String pool when using the + operator. When i create a new variable with the same text as greeting (so it should be in the string pool) and compare that with the concatinated variable, it still returns false. (hope that makes sense)

Comment: I don't think there is a checking here. Without compiler optimization, the `+` operation on `String`s is actually creating `StringBuilder` object, invoking `append` and `toString` methods. For example, with `a` is a String and `b` is whatever, `a+b` is the same as `new StringBuilder(a).append(b).toString()`

Answer (score 3):

In your case,  there are 3 String objects will be created in String pool. `greeting`and `goodbye` will be created in heap.

javac has an optimization to put `greeting`and `goodbye` to String pool if `hello`, `word` and `bye` are final, the `+` operation will be performed on compile time instead of run time.
Two of bellow codes will be compiled to the same byte code.

```java
final String hello = "Hello";
final String world = " World!";
final String bye = "Bye";
String greeting = hello + world;
String goodbye = bye + world;
```

```java
final String hello = "Hello";
final String world = " World!";
final String bye = "Bye";
String greeting = "Hello World!";
String goodbye = "Bye World!";
```

Comment: The 5 objects seems correct, although as Ahmad Shabib mentions when i do the check with and operator and not the equals method the last two don't seem to be in the string pool.

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. I'm going to edit my answer.